# Should I use memory addresses as application-level identifiers in C++?

Tags: c++

I am learning C++ and I am wondering whether it is ever a good idea to use an object's allocated memory address as a temporary application level identifier.

Comment: Identifier for what?

Comment: @JamesMcNellis For differentiating similar object instances from a single class for example.

Comment: As I posted bellow, your will shoot yourself in the foot if you do this lightly, better not to do it at all. Remember, an address can be reused by another object once your object has been freed, you have to be very careful to know when an ID stops referring to the object you assume it identifies.

Comment: Well, OK, but the snag is that NOT using adresses as ID's is that it makes apps that continually move around large and complex objects 'very, very very difficult'.  It is not remotely practical to pass/signal around, say, objects containing 10MB of buffered network data, in any other way.  One trick to avoiding use of a freed object is to never free them - circulate them on queues and pools.

Comment: ..and yes, before you say - that has its own set of issues, double-posting an object back to a pool, for example.  I know this only too well :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you create the object with new(), the returned object instance pointer IS, effectively, the object.  It becomes an application identifier until explicitly dispose()d.  I try not to build objects on stacks - I write too much mutithreaded code and so it's just too dangerous.

Obviously, there are many things you cannot do with addresses as ID - you cannot decrement/increment one to point at the object with the preceeding/succeeding ID, for example.

Comment: Excellent Martin. This is the answer I was looking for. Thank you all for your input.

Comment: @Martin James: That's not true, new returns a pointer to your object, which is essentially a address that you have to explicitly deference (object->value or *simple_type) to get to the object, the object is located where the address returned by new points to.

Comment: C++ does not have a `dispose()` function.

Comment: @DmitriyRyajov - indeed, but the address of the object is unique, unless the memory-management is broke, in which case you are stuffed anyway because your system is about to collapse.

Comment: @Xeo OK, OK.. dispose(), deallocate(), free(), delete(), destruct(), getRidOf(), annhiliate(), exterminate(), maximizeEntropy().. whatever() :)

Comment: I use object addresses, supplied by new(), as effective IDs throughout my apps. How am I supposed to pass them into methods, queue them to other threads, store them in lists and other collections, if not my address?   Copying would be a functional and performance disaster - I would be surprised if any app got as far as displaying the main form never mind anything like network servers.  I would never know if some other part of my app had a copy, (~~shudder~~).

Comment: Your confusing terminology, your talking about pointers not IDs. I assume that's what you mean by "I use object addresses, supplied by new(), as effective IDs throughout my apps.", unless your referring to passing around the value of the address and then casting that to a pointer? In the best case you make me doubt about your grasp of the matter, in the worst case you are confusing a newbie, please stop using the wrong terminology.

Comment: I'm already guilty of confusing terminology, (dispose - I've had a C++ project open all week, I should know it's delete()).  It's like this.  When I create an object, 'messPool=new TmessagePool();' I don't care where the object data members, vtable pointer, method addresses and all the rest of the gunge is located.  The object is, to me, stored in the variable 'TmessagePool *messPool;'.  I can pass this value into methods or queue it off to another thread and then create another Tmesspool in the *messpool variable.  So long as I always create objects with new, the pointer IS the object.

Comment: @Martin James: I understand what your trying to say, but it is still incorrect, and it's a subtle but fundamental difference. `TmessagePool *messPool;` is not the object, `messPool` stores the address to your object, which is somewhere on the heap (possibly on the stack if you do `int *i = &stack_object`), without that distinction you cannot possibly understand or explain things like pointer arithmetic. I suggest you to edit your answer so that others do not get confused.

Comment: It's a philosophy, rather than a statement of absolute accuracy.  It is obviously impossible to store an complete object in just one pointer - most people will get that.  After a bit, though, it becomes second-nature to look upon the object address as the actual object itself. It just happens - it's natural.  If I had to think about how complex multi-aggregated objects are stored, I would go insane, (some would say.. :).  To anyone who is confused - the addresses of objects allocated with 'new' MAY be looked upon as the objects themselves, but only because the address is unique per object.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably not the best idea. If nothing else, it severely limits your future ability to move/clone the objects. It also increases risk if you rely on this to find an object from its ID -- a stale reference can result in a crash.

Comment: It can also be a problem if these IDs are used in security contexts and can be predicted by the attacker.

Comment: @Alexey: For the attacker to provide an identifier that falls in inaccessible memory is potentially much easier and almost as bad (DoS instead of privilege escalation).

Comment: ?? It makes it much easier to move the objects! You just move the address and either nil the var that was used to contain it or reseat the var by creating/depooling another *object to the same var.  Cloning objects - best never, ever done, especially in multithreaded apps. For the purposes of security, however, I agree - virtually useless.  Security is a huge issue and surpasses the scope of the OP question, (I think:).  The OP was only interested in an ID within one app, not as some distributed ID.

Comment: @MartinJames Umm... if someone has a lingering reference to the object's 'ID' and you go and move the object in memory underneath, that reference will dangle and potentially cause issues if dereferenced, particularly if you assume that the ID is the address of the object.  (Unless you refeference count, of course.)

Comment: Don't move objects!  Why would I want to move an object?  The operator new has allocated some space and constructed the object.. somewhere.  Why would I want to move it? I can't say if I've ever moved an object in my life - I certainly can't remember ever doing so.

Comment: @MartinJames I think we're talking past each other here. We clearly have very different interpretations of the term 'identifier'...

Comment: Yeah - you're probably right. It's 4:30 in the morning and I spent all of yesterday fighting the linker - it has some sort of indigestion and keeps throwing up pages of 'unresolved':(

Answer (score 2):

You should not do it. Because in addition to what has already been mentioned here, addresses are reused and your id, which is essentially a pointer, can be reused by some other object once the old object has been freed. If, for example, this id is going to be used to access some session information, you could very well be accessing/modifying the session of some other user - not a good thing. You can however use the address in combination with some other information, such as the thread id, current system time, etc...